# How can i use Reflection to create instance of Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Controls.ServerFileBrowserEditor

Tags: c#, reflection, tfs

I am build my custom build process template Argument of type `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Controls.ServerFileBrowserEditor`

Since the type is not accessible outside of assembly so i using reflection to create an instance of it.

I wanted to create instance of `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Controls.ServerFileBrowserEditor`

because i need to apply filter type filter on it.

How can i create instance of it and show it to user.

Comment: You're asking for trouble if you try to use reflection to access private or internal methods/classes. They're private or internal for a reason: Because you, as a consumer, shouldn't be able to use them.

Answer (score 1):

As in the comments mentioned, using private types should never be done in a production environment. To create an instance of a private type itself is not a problem:

```
//reference an accessible type to get the assembly fast and easy
var asm = typeof (Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Controls.AzureEditor).Assembly;
//get the desired type
var type = asm.GetTypes().Single(x => x.Name == "ServerFileBrowserEditor");
//get the constructor
var ctor = type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
//create the object by invoking the constructor
var obj = ctor.Invoke(null);
```

Comment: @PavanTiwari yes you are right, this code just creates an instance. To be honest i don't know when and how to use an `UITypeEditor` object at all. Maybe you can add to your post the scenario how you would normally use this type and why its not working with a so created object.